# Output the integers in a String separately and output it afterwards

Tags: java, split

The user will input a string and the program should recognize the integers. 
If the user inputs `Hello12 3` it should output:

```
The integral numbers are:
id1     12
id2     3
```

but in my code, it outputs

```
The integral numbers are:
int1     
int2     
int3     
int4     
int5     
int6     12
int7     3
```

How should i fix it?
My code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LexicalAnalyzer {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        int j=0;

        System.out.println("Lexical Analyzer for Algebraic Expressions\n");
        System.out.print("Enter the String: ");
        str = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String length is: "+str.length());
        System.out.println("\nThe integral numbers are: \n");
        String intNum = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ");
        String[] intSplit = intNum.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<intSplit.length;i++){
            System.out.println("int"+(i+1)+"     "+intSplit[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're replacing non-numeric characters with whitespaces, then splitting the result on a whitespace character. The array that it spits out is going to have a bunch of empty elements in it as a result... elements that you've still got to iterate over before you get to your numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wasting time (CPU resources) on modifying the string, just search for what you want:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher(str);
for (int i = 1; m.find(); i++)
    System.out.println("int" + i + "     " + m.group());
```

Comment: It's now working. Thank you! I didn't know that exists

Comment: I have a question. What if i use a delimiter? Like for example i have a string of `m^ar y^ear` and i want it to output `m`,`ar`, `y` and `ear` separately, how am i supposed to do it?

Comment: i found out that i just have to change the pattern to `[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: @Meryel `split()` uses a regular expression to split the input string, which also "eliminates" the matched substring from the result. A `find()` loop uses a regular expression to select the matched substring, skipping over (eliminating) the unmatched text. So, in that case, you can either split on spaces and hats (`split("[ ^]+")`), or find sequences of characters that are not spaces and hats (using `"[^ ^]+"`).

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing every non-numeric character with a space. You need to replace it with `""` so that there are no extra spaces. Then you split on space and you will get the desired result. Also, you need to preserve the spaces between numbers by using `[^0-9\\s]` so that the spaces are not replaced by `""` (empty String).

Replace:

```
String intNum = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ");
```

with:

```
String intNum = str.replaceAll("[^0-9\\s]", "");
```

Comment: @JonK did it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Since the `split()` is on space only, why keep all *whitespace* characters? It should be `[^0-9 ]`, and you should call `trim()` too, to prevent leading blank value from `split()`, and the split should be on multiple spaces, i.e. `split(" +")`. Anything less is an incomplete answer.